# Parsing error with the default ANTLR4 grammar for the PDDL language

Tags: antlr4

I am relatively new to ANTLR so please bear with me.

I'm trying to parse a valid PDDL file and it seems [the given grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pddl/Pddl.g4) has some kind of error I cannot seem to find.

```
line 3:13 mismatched input 'at' expecting NAME
line 8:18 mismatched input 'at' expecting NAME
line 8:25 mismatched input '?a' expecting {'(', NAME, NUMBER}
```

A minimal input that reproduces the error:

```
(define (domain foo)
(:types car place)
(:functions (at ?x - car) - place)

(:action move 
 :parameters (?a - place ?c - car)
 :precondition ()
 :effect (assign (at ?c) ?a)))
```

If it is of any use, the "official" BNF can be found here:
https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scommv/IPC-14/repository/kovacs-pddl-3.1-2011.pdf

I'm using the latest stable antlr4 (4.7.2). I have tried generating Java and Python code, but it outputs the same error.

Comment: Just a side note, the grammars from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 are contributed by users (not from the ANTLR developers). And there is no review proces of these contributed grammars. It is more than likely that the grammar you're using is just incomplete/wrong.

Comment: Oh! had no idea. I'll edit the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that `(:functions (at ?x - car) - place)` cannot be parsed as a `functionsDef`. Have a look at this rule and the rules it's made up of:

```
functionsDef
   : '(' ':functions' functionList ')'
   ;

functionList
   : ( atomicFunctionSkeleton+ ( '-' functionType )? )*
   ;

atomicFunctionSkeleton
   : '(' functionSymbol typedVariableList ')'
   ;

functionSymbol
   : NAME
   ;
```

As you can see, a `functionSymbol` can only be a name, yet the input `at` is being tokenised as a keyword, not as a `NAME`. If `at` is a valid `functionSymbol`, it must be added to it as an alternative:

```
functionSymbol
   : NAME
   | 'at'
   ;
```

Or, if more keywords are valid names, introduce a `name` rule that matches them:

```
functionSymbol
   : name
   ;

name
   : NAME
   | 'at'
   | 'start'
   | 'end'
   | ...
   ;
```

And is seems `- place` should be matched by the rule `functionType`:

```
functionType
   : 'number'
   ;
```

but that can apparently only be the keyword `number`. If you add `'place'` as an alternative:

```
functionType
   : 'number'
   | 'place'
   ;
```

it would be parsed correctly.

Assuming the input `(:functions (at ?x - car) - place)` is valid, then there are already 2 errors in that grammar for a `functionsDef` alone. I would be hesitant to use it.

### EDIT

For all the literal keywords inside parser rules (like `'at'`, `'begin'`, `'end'`, ...) ANTLR will create tokens for behind the scenes. So it will be the same as something like this:

```
AT    : 'at';
BEGIN : 'begin';
END   : 'end';
...
NAME  : LETTER ANY_CHAR*;
```

So the input `at` will always be tokenised as an `AT` token, never as a `NAME` token. If you want `at` to be sometimes recognised as an `AT` and other times as a `NAME`, do as I previously recommended: introduce a parser rule called `name` and let it match `NAME` and all keyword-tokens and use `name` in your parser rules instead of `NAME`.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and detailed response, you explained the issues very well. What is left for me to understand is why ANTLR chooses to tokenize 'at' as a keyword and not as a NAME, because I think the NAME rules are enough to accept 'at' as a NAME. Could you explain that for me please?

Comment: @CatOsMandros checkout my **EDIT**